# Magento 1.8 backend loading without css,js

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

The frontend is working perfectly well but the backend misses out on the css and js. The source points correctly to skin/adminhtml/.... and so on.

- I tried clearing cache folder.
- I tried changing `unsecure_url` an `secure_url` as well in phpmyadmin.
- I tried changing `store_id` in `core_website` and `core_store` in phpmyadmin.
- I tried changing `merge_files` in `core_config_data` in phpmyadmin.

What I didnt try was punching through the laptop screen, and I'm seriously considering it.

Pls save my laptop. Thanks already.

Comment: Check your secure_url  and unsecure_url  with scope `store` and scope id 0

Comment: can we have browser console screenshot?

Comment: I checked the source. And its leading to a wrong link. I.e. when I click on a css link that it specifies in the page source, nothing opens because the link it tries to visit is: "localhost:1234/magento/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/d5380273810gsbmd682/media/css/54cwujsioheebe582bj.css". Whereas the correct link, which on entering in the URL bar does open the required CSS file is: "localhost:1234/magento/media/css/54cwujsioheebe582bj.css"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use some debug tools to track all process of loading? (like xdebug).
For me in the same situations easiest ways are:
- use all possible degugger tools 
- look for source code of page (find by name if everything is connected fine (styles and js) 
- try to "hardcode" needed css temporary to the page you now degugging.

If all of this doesn't help you - please add screenshot and put your laptop till answer appear here.